# Removing most of unittesting output on failure

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests in python 3.4 and I want to change the output on failure of the unit testing framework. I'm currently using `nose` and `testtools`. I'm trying to get a simple example working, this is what it looks like.

```
from testtools import TestCase
from testtools.matchers import Equals

class Test_Class(TestCase):
    def test_stuff(self):
        self.expectThat([5],Equals([4]))
```

with the output being

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: example.Test_Class.test_stuff
----------------------------------------------------------------------
testtools.testresult.real._StringException: Failed expectation: {{{
File "/home/john/simplecase/test1/example.py", line 6, in test_stuff
    self.expectThat([5],Equals([4]))
  File "/opt/python/Python-3.4.1/bin/lib/python3.4/site-packages/testtools-1.1.0-py3.4.egg    /testtools/testcase.py", line 474, in expectThat
    postfix_content="MismatchError: " + str(mismatch_error)
MismatchError: [4] != [5]
}}}

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError: Forced Test Failure
```

This error message is too verbose for me to use. I could have up to 50 tests being compared and this makes it hard to analyze the failures. I want the output to be something like

```
MismatchError: [4] != [5]
```

I tried reducing the verbosity of `nosetests` to 1 and 0 but that didn't help. I've also looked into logging and annotations but these only allow me to append data to the failure message instead of changing it

Comment: Erm.. isn't that verbosity exactly what identifies the failing test, which is all the more important if you have many of them? You could generate a summary separately by grepping the report.

Comment: @YannVernier Well, I don't need to know where the file is located in the testtoools package to figure out what the error is. If I can remove most of this I would use annotations to output the file that failed and the variables that were compared. Ya, using grep is the other option I was thinking of.Just redirecting stdout and stderr to a file and then taking what I need out of that